# UITableView Section Indexing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I'm creating a tableview with an index, my index array has 26 values (A-Z) but my data source may only have a few sections (A,D,S).

My challenge is that the user selects an index value but the incorrect section should not display, if I'm not mistaken this is due to the index value returned is different to the selected value for row.

In my example above selecting index 'D' will return a value of 3, but the section value for 'D' in my data source is 1. Is this normal, if it is hows the best way to handle this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is the correct behavior. Solution would be to create your index with only the values that actually contain data.

When more data is added, add new sections if required.

Comment: Unfortunately the index looks very strange if only partly populated, I'm trying to replicate the way the contacts application works, this displays a full index regardless of the data available.